# Autorun file on USB drive in OS X

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, autorun, disk-image

I would like to have my USB flash drive auto-run a file on it when plugged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Automator and folder actions on the /Volumes/ folder.

Just open Automator, add a new folder action and click Choose Folder. When the popup comes up press Command-Shift-g and type /Volumes/. Now just create a Workflow App that will be triggered whenever a device is mounted.

Comment: When I started it up the first thing was choose a template and a chose folder action, then I was in the program and it already knew choose folder. So how do I enter '/Volumes/' and how do I say when it should be triggered? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have my mac right now and I am no Automator expert. Maybe you will have more success at http://apple.stackexchange.com ? This article may also help you: http://automator.us/examples-08.html

Comment: @nmat No need suggesting another site, this only encourages cross posting. This question could have been migrated to Apple.SE if it doesn't get any useful answers, but it's now been [asked anyway](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/flash-drive-autorun-script-on-mac).

Comment: @JShoe Did you get any further with the example nmat gave you?

Comment: @slhck no actually...