# Change password of encrypted disk image in OS X with Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords, usb-flash-drive, disk-image

I would like a program that would exist on my flash drive that, when run, would

- open an encrypted disk image with a stored password
- then change the password to a random number
- store it for using it the next time

Can this be done?

Comment: As this is related to [your previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/316414/flash-drive-autorun-script-on-mac), I edited out the part about what you are asking here.

Comment: This will be fun once storing the password fails for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know shell script, you can write s simple program that does that. Use `hdiutil` to change an encrypted disk password:

```
hdiutil chpass [image_name]
```

It will interactively ask you for your previous password and new password so you have to use some pipes or maybe [expect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html). To generate a random number, `echo $RANDOM` should do. To store the passwords you can use a simple text file, if you don't mind keeping it unprotected.

Comment: It's not a tube, it's a pipe. hdiutil expects that you enter your passwords manually. If you want to automate this process you should use `expect`. Take a look at some Wikipedia examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Examples

Comment: Actually, there are options -oldstdinpass and -newstdinpass that allow passing in the passwords via stdin on two lines, as in `(echo "oldpw"; echo "newpw") | hdiutil <img>`.